# SharePoint 2013 Manage Metadata Term Store Orphaned Terms Delete

Tags: term-store, term-set, orphan

I'm Facing a problem with Orphaned Terms, 
I cannot delete them from term store management tool under Managed Metadata Service Application.

Is there is anyway to clear it?

I try to delete them using powershell and I get this exception

> This operation is invalid in the Orphaned Terms term set.  The operation failed.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have checked this and got some interesting facts.

Direct solution:

delete them from list at : [site url]/Lists/TaxonomyHiddenList/AllItems.aspx

Solution captured after evaluating below articles:

1.[How to remove obsolete/orphaned items from TaxonomyHiddenList](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/28053/how-to-remove-obsolete-orphaned-items-from-taxonomyhiddenlist)

2.https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c835a182-338d-47bd-b3d7-776a499f8af5/how-to-remove-obsoleteorphaned-items-from-taxonomyhiddenlist?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious#d20572c7-1b5d-46c3-a583-912698e3df3b

and

3.http://www.threewill.com/finding-taxonomyhiddenlist/

Thanks,

Buddi